# Any risk when I call Freertos APIs directly from Cmsis os based Application?

Tags: freertos

I have used the tool STM32Cube to generate an application integrated with cmsis os.

In my code, if I use the function osTimerCreate then it return successfully.

But if I call the freertos function xTimerCreate, it always return fail.

so question is that what is differences between them? in my opinion there's nothing different here.

Thank in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a problem doing that.  Suggest stepping through the xTimerCreate() call in the debugger to see why it fails.

Comment: Sorry, now I just have a chance go back this problem. I have debugged and everything is ok in its creation, but its callback seems never is executed. This problem also occurs when I use xTaskCreate function. pls help

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I have made it work by doing these:

1. Change optimize level from O(3) to O(0)
2. Put the variable TimerHandle_t xTimers as global ( outside of Thread body).

I actually don't know why, but happy as it works now :)

It would be great if anyone can explain something. Thanks